# asp.net listview highlight row on click

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, onclick

I know how to set up listview to highlight a row when you click a link, image, etc but I am just wondering if it is possible to set it up to highlight a row when you click on any of its cells, not just on a predefined control.

Is that possible?

I way around it would be to setup onclick of each `<td>` but no idea how to reset the background colour when you click on another cell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use Jquery on the client side:

```
$("#myTable tr").click( function () 
{
   $("#myTable tr").each(function () { $(this).removeClass("selected")}); 
   $(this).addClass("selected"); 
});​
```

An example fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/9pmcA/26/

Comment: Sorry I've only started with the likes of jquery/css. Where do I put the above in my .aspx page? Thanks

Comment: I have placed it in my HeaderContent but its not doing anything.

Comment: @sd_dracula: Have you add the **Jquery** library?? if not, have look at **http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works**

Comment: Yes it is added, to the scripts folder but it still wont work. v1.4.1

Comment: Did you <script src="jquery-1.4.1.js"/> in your html?