# listview select row without postBack

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, cell, selecteditem

I have a list view with many rows and have it set so that if you click on a cell it highlights it.

When clicking on the first column cells the whole row is highlighted (SelectedItemTeplate of listvew) the problem is that when you select a row all the highlighted cells gets reset as the page refreshes.

Is it possible to just highlight without postback?

Comment: What code are you using to make the `ListView`?

Comment: I have passed in a data source and it created the listview for me. And I can see if I hover over the select link, the javascript has __doPostBack('ctl...

Comment: @sd_dracula : Are you asking the same question **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052761/asp-net-listview-highlight-row-on-click/11053166#comment14462018_11053166** twice??

Comment: No that was for just a table, not the listview element which is slightly different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to just highlight without postback?

Yes, do this highlighting entirely on the client side via JQuery or Javascript.

For example, assuming every row in the listview has a class applied, you can do this in JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('.your_class').live("click",function() { $(this).attr("class","highlight");   });

});
```

What the above code will do is that any html element in your page that has the class ".your_class" applied, will change to another class ("highlight" on the example) when it's clicked.

Comment: do i just put that into a <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script> ?

Comment: @sd_dracula yes, and don't forget to include the jQuery library. You can include it from Google's CDN: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js