# Clearing outline onMouseLeave JQuery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

I am new to JQuery

This thread is a half-duplicate of [my older thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17424355/asp-net-listview-with-clickable-rows-which-highlights-selected-item/17424479?noredirect=1#17424479)

The main problem is that I want to create a box around the current item to which mouse is pointing, and when mouse leaves that item the box will disappear.

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

 <div class="clickable" url="http://www.google.com">
    Google
</div>

<div class="clickable" url="http://www.bing.com">
    Bing
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $("div.clickable").mouseover(function () {
 //        $(this).css("outline-style", "solid");
 //        $(this).css("outline-color", "Navy");
 //        $(this).css("outline-width", "thin");
    $("#div.clickable").each(function () { $(this).removeClass("Selected") });
    $(this).addClass("Selected");
 });
 </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("div.clickable").click(
    function () {
        window.location = $(this).attr("url");
    });
</script>
```

And Style would be

```
.clickable
{
  cursor:pointer;
  cursor: hand;
}

.Selected
{
  outline-style:solid;
  outline-color:Navy;
  outline-width:thin;
}
```

Yet it is not working when mouse goes over the other item. it does not clear the outline of the previous item.

Comment: You can do this with pure css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use CSS pseudo class `:hover`:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qxdeW/)

```
.clickable:hover{outline:thin solid navy}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with pure css:

```
.clickable:hover{
      outline-style:solid;
      outline-color:Navy;
      outline-width:thin;
}
.clickable
{
      cursor:pointer;
      outline-style:none;
      outline-color:transaprent;
      outline-width:none;
}
```

no js needed.